# Receive data from client-side on server-side

Tags: javascript, php, html, rest, apache

I have an html page where clients insert a url so that it can be stored on a file on the server side.

The issue that I am having is that I cannot figure out how to receive client data on the server

Here is my html script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="url" id="link"><br>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Download</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var url= document.getElementById("link").value
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I send the data of the "url" variable to my server?

I am using apache so it naturally supports php

Inside the function I tried to use fetch in combination with a php file

```
function myFunction() {
    var url= document.getElementById("link").value
    fetch(".php", {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                            },
    "body": JSON.stringify(url)
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

And the php file

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $link = json_decode($data);
        echo $link ;
    }
```

I was expecting to receive the url from the text input but instead the console.log returned the whole html script

Comment: I can't see any php file specified in your question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, just update the `fetch(".php", {` line.
**You need to give a file name here.**

For example, if the name of the PHP file which processes the data is `server.php`, you have to write `fetch("server.php", {`

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Such a silly mistake from me, thank you very much sir!